# Add text above HTML5 Video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

Need Help on adding text on top of, so the text is overlaying an HTML 5 Video, And I also need to add a form inputs and buttons as well below is my HTML5 Video Code.

```
<video id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="play();">
<source src="video/Motion.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 60):

Surely you are looking for more than this:

```
<div class="container">
    <video id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="play();">
        <source src="video/Motion.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Content above your video</p>
        <form>
            <p>Content Below Your Video</p>
            <label for="input">Form Input Label</label>
            <input id="input" name="input" value="" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to put the content on top of the video, you would use some kind of positioning:

```
.container { position:relative; }
.container video {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Hello what I mean is  text OVER the video or FLOATING above the video

Comment: Updated example to suit your needs.

Comment: [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/NAeJD/), didn't have an MP4 capable browser to hand however

Comment: Thanks Robertc and Matthew.. It helps me a lot

Comment: This will overlay on whole page. Not a good solution though. But broad vision. thanks.

Comment: The container is positioned relatively, so it will only fill the container, not the whole page.

Answer (score 5):

You can use top and left position to be in percentage. as it will auto adjust top text when the window content size will change

```html
<div class="container">
  <video id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="play();">
    <source src="video/Motion.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <div class="overlayText">
    <p id="topText">Content above your video</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.overlayText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#topText {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  align-self: center;
}
```