# Text over video html

Tags: html, css

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for designing a website. I was able to add a picture as background and then write over it, but it's supposed to be different woth a video.  How do I add a textbox over a video? Do I need to set it as background? thank you

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/b8g8chto/
Very simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you are looking for more than this:

```
<div class="container">
    <video id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="play();">
        <source src="video/Motion.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Content above your video</p>
        <form>
            <p>Content Below Your Video</p>
            <label for="input">Form Input Label</label>
            <input id="input" name="input" value="" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to put the content on top of the video, you would use some kind of positioning:

```
.container { position:relative; }
.container video {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422105/add-text-above-html5-video)