# Background video is covering up HTML heading tags

Tags: html, css, mp4

I tried changing the `Z-index`'s to do what I want but its not fixing it. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want my headings to be on top of the background video. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```css
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

   background: url("../vid/everything.mp4");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 82px;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">

  <video loop muted autoplay poster="assets/vid/everything.mp4" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
  <source src="assets/vid/everything.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="100">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-6">
        <h1>Welcome! Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Get Started</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</section>
```

Right now it just shows my video and the headings are covered. I tried messing with my CSS file but cant figure it out. I've also got rid of the `"Background: url "` when testing and it wont work either when doing so. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422105/add-text-above-html5-video

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">

  <video loop muted autoplay poster="assets/vid/everything.mp4" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
  <source src="assets/vid/everything.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="100">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-6 vid-txt">
        <h1>Welcome! Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Get Started</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</section>
```

```
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

   background: url("../vid/everything.mp4");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 82px;
}
.vid-txt{
  position: absolute;
}
```